# Soligor to Canon Adapter

Tags: adapter

I have a Soligor 500 mm F8 mirror lens.Does anyone make an adapter so that I can use the lens on a Canon 5D?  HAs anyone found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

Most Soligor mirror lenses have a T2 mount. To use one with your Canon EOS 5D (or any other Canon EOS camera) you need a [T2 to EF](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0001DZ6C8) adapter.

Realize that you will need to manually focus and shoot in manual exposure mode with such a lens. Also note that there are three tiny set screws that must be tightened after you attach your lens to the adapter to prevent the inner part of the adapter from spinning inside the outer part of the adapter. Rotate the lens so that the focusing mark is on top when the adapter is attached to your camera and tighten the three set screws to keep it there.